# CyberSource Secure Acceptance integration with REST Api in php

Tags: php, payment-gateway, cybersource

I'm trying to integrate **Cyber Source** Payment gateway in php using **REST API**. And I found following reference link in [github](https://github.com/e-payment/cybersource-secure-acceptance/tree/master/php)

After required changes finally I can able to login (Authenticate) to Cyber source but, Im getting below error. (I can check the logs from Cyber Source)

**req_reference_number: 474 => ERROR 101 - Request parameters are invalid or missing**

```
signed: true

Array
(
    [auth_trans_ref_no] => 474
    [decision] => ERROR
    [message] => Request parameters are invalid or missing
    [reason_code] => 101
    [req_access_key] => 5e00e27842d73381b0**************
    [req_amount] => 569
    [req_bill_to_address_city] => Mountain View
    [req_bill_to_address_country] => US
    [req_bill_to_address_line1] => 1 My Apartment
    [req_bill_to_address_line2] => 2 nd street
    [req_bill_to_address_postal_code] => 94043
    [req_bill_to_address_state] => CA
    [req_bill_to_email] => someemail@somedomain.com
    [req_bill_to_forename] => Elavarasan
    [req_bill_to_phone] => 6508764564
    [req_bill_to_surname] => Natarajan
    [req_currency] => USD
    [req_customer_ip_address] => 127.0.0.1
    [req_device_fingerprint_id] => v1rh0p44gpnhag1a7mfp9tst25
    [req_item_0_code] => KFLTFDIV
    [req_item_0_name] => KFLTFDIV
    [req_item_0_quantity] => 1
    [req_item_0_sku] => sku001
    [req_item_0_unit_price] => 20.00
    [req_item_1_code] => KFLTFD70
    [req_item_1_name] => KFLTFD70
    [req_item_1_quantity] => 1
    [req_item_1_sku] => sku002
    [req_item_1_unit_price] => 10.00
    [req_line_item_count] => 2
    [req_locale] => en-us
    [req_merchant_defined_data1] => MDD1
    [req_merchant_defined_data2] => MDD2
    [req_merchant_defined_data3] => MDD3
    [req_merchant_defined_data4] => MDD4
    [req_merchant_descriptor] => Krungsri
    [req_override_custom_cancel_page] => http://localhost/cyphp/sa-wm/response.php
    [req_override_custom_receipt_page] => http://localhost/cyphp/sa-wm/response.php
    [req_profile_id] => *******************************
    [req_reference_number] => 474
    [req_transaction_type] => sale
    [req_transaction_uuid] => 5aa6329409169
    [required_fields] => payment_method
    [signature] => IJ0iEsOJLZe2W4dNrogdzp8op8Evon2wU1KvA3W6SzM=
    [signed_date_time] => 2018-03-12T07:57:00Z
    [signed_field_names] => decision,req_access_key,req_profile_id,req_transaction_uuid,req_transaction_type,req_reference_number,req_amount,req_currency,req_line_item_count,req_locale,req_override_custom_receipt_page,req_override_custom_cancel_page,auth_trans_ref_no,req_item_0_code,req_item_0_name,req_item_0_quantity,req_item_0_sku,req_item_0_unit_price,req_item_1_code,req_item_1_name,req_item_1_quantity,req_item_1_sku,req_item_1_unit_price,req_bill_to_forename,req_bill_to_surname,req_bill_to_email,req_bill_to_phone,req_bill_to_address_line1,req_bill_to_address_line2,req_bill_to_address_city,req_bill_to_address_state,req_bill_to_address_country,req_bill_to_address_postal_code,req_customer_ip_address,req_device_fingerprint_id,req_merchant_defined_data1,req_merchant_defined_data2,req_merchant_defined_data3,req_merchant_defined_data4,req_merchant_descriptor,required_fields,reason_code,message,signed_field_names,signed_date_time
    [utf8] => ✓
)
```

If I rename or remove any parameter, then authentication is failed. So I hope that, I'm passing some wrong value. But I couldn't find out which one is..

I tried to change almost every field values which I'm passing, but every time getting same error

**ERROR 101 - Request parameters are invalid or missing**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found sample code (php) from Cyber Source, we just have to configure as per the credential. Here is the [link](http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/Secure_Acceptance_SOP/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=creating_profile.05.8.html)

[Source Code](http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/samples/sa_sop/php_sop.zip)

You have to define you Secret key in `security.php` file

```
define ('SECRET_KEY', '7f15d699ff14461b9a84*****');
```

And,
 `access_key` and `profile_id` in `signeddatafields.php` file

```
<input type="hidden" name="access_key" value="5e00e27842d73******">
<input type="hidden" name="profile_id" value="43C533AC-****-****-****-*********">
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

I only did the SOAP as well, but after a look at their rest v1 example, it looks like the api key and secret key are passed to create a paytoken in the [Apiclient](https://github.com/CyberSource/cybersource-rest-sdk-php/blob/master/lib/ApiClient.php). An authorization payment should be something like this(after u install the sdk):

```
<?php
use \CyberSource\Authorizations as Authorizations;
use \CyberSource\Configuration as Configuration;

class CyberSource {

      private $config;

      function __construct($apiKey, $secretKey) {
         // pass apikey and secretkey to configuration 
         $this->config = new Configuration($apiKey, $secretKey);
      }

      private function runAuth($this->config) {
          $api = new Authorizations($this->config);
          $jsonPayload = // ur json request payload

          try{
            // pass the request json payload object 
            $response = $api->createAuthorization($jsonPayload);
          } catch (\E $e) {
             //throw error here
          }
      }

}
```

if you have to use v2 then u need to read this [pdf](http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/REST_API/Getting_Started/Getting_Started_REST_API.pdf) there are several things you need to add to the header for account authentication.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, yeah you are correct. I have updated my question, please check it.